# jQuery Dropdown Menu Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a website with a settings feature and I have this button. I want the options and other links to appear in a dropdown menu when hovered over. I have the code that I think should work but it won't work for some reason.

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xp4rfLbL/)

Javascript ,CSS and HTML:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#settings').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#settingDrop').css('visibilty', 'visible'); 
  });
  $('#settingDrop, #settings').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#settingDrop').css('visibilty', 'hidden'); 
  });
});
```

```css
#settings {
  width: 40px;
  background-image: url(http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/23171.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  background-position: center;
  float:left;
}

#settingDrop {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  float:left;
  top:55px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.navbar {
  margin-left:
    width: 170px;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'settings' class='navbar'></div>
<div id = 'settingDrop'></div>
```

Comment: what error you find??

Comment: Nothing happens. I checked my Javascript and everything seems to be all right. The dropdown just doesn't appear

Comment: That is because of a typo, it should be `visibility` instead of `visibilty` in the click-function. Fixed in Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z0ta8Ly9/

Comment: Works somewhat, but doesn't stay when I hover over the dropdown. I still feel like an idiot though.....

Comment: @Jasch1 you need to make drop down appear on hover and hide when cursor moved

Comment: @sanojlawrence I believe that's what I have now

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo for `visibility`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#settings').mouseenter(function(){
       $('#settingDrop').css('visibility', 'visible'); 
    });
    $('#settingDrop, #settings').mouseleave(function(){
       $('#settingDrop').css('visibility', 'hidden'); 
    });
});
```

As a note and for a shorter code, using the CSS `display:none` and jQuery `show(milliseconds)`and `hide(milliseconds)` is quicker, you can even animate it by using time, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#settings').mouseenter(function(){
       $('#settingDrop').show(500); 
    });

    $('#settingDrop, #settings').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#settingDrop').hide(500); 
    });

});
```

Same with `fadeIn(milliseconds)` and `fadeOut(milliseconds)`

And change `visibility:hidden` to `display:none`.

*** EDIT ***

This is for the time, to have the menu go away after a few seconds (in this case 2, 2000 is in milliseconds):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#settings').click(function(){
       $('#settingDrop').fadeIn(500);
    });

    $('#settingDrop, #settings').mouseleave(function(){
        var time = setInterval(function(){
            $('#settingDrop').fadeOut(500);
            clearInterval(time);
        }, 2000);            
    });

});
```

This is the updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xp4rfLbL/2/

Comment: Works somewhat, but doesn't stay when I hover over the dropdown. I still feel like an idiot though.....

Comment: Ok, then you should add a timer to make it go away after a few seconds. I'm changing the code, hold on.